# How to animate textField's height grows in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, animation, swiftui, textfield

With below code, the textField grows when its line is increased and smaller than 5 lines. But there is no animation on textField's height change, how could I apply an animation on that change?

```
struct TextClipView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var textClipModel: TextClipModel
    private var placeholderString = "Type your text here!"
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            VStack(spacing: 20) {
                Spacer()
                    .frame(height: 80)
                
                TextField(placeholderString, text: $textClipModel.textClip, axis: .vertical)
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                    .lineLimit(5)
                Spacer()
            }
            .frame(
                width: proxy.size.width,
                height: proxy.size.height
            )
        }
        .background(Color.green.opacity(0.2))
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does 'TextClipModel' come from?  And at what line are you attempting to animate text field's height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that by applying the the `.animation` modifier to the TextField like so:

```
TextField(placeholderString, text: $textClipModel.textClip, axis: .vertical)
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                .lineLimit(5)
                .animation(.default, value: textClipModel.textClip)
```

With this small change your TextField's height increases or decreases will be animated. I already tested it.
Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: Thanks, it works. And `.animation(xx, value: xx)` monitor the inputted textClip changes, could I know how it could known when the changes required grows or decrease a line? Idk how it is worked internally.

Comment: This basically listens to changes of the textClip property and redraws the compnent if needed. Here you can find a fun tutorial about it: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/animating-views-and-transitions. If you've found my solution helpful, please consider at least upvoting it :)

Comment: Accepted, I would look that Apple tutorial, cheers!